# Work order send and response software (two forms in one ticket)?

Tags: windows, tablet

I'd like to find a software that allows you to fill out a custom work order form and then get a second form (filled out on a tablet by a maintenance worker). I work for a property management company, and we're constantly sending out maintenance people to fix clogged drains, etc.

The basic idea is Person 1 at the office fills out Form 1 detailing the repair needed, which then goes to Person 2 who fixes the problem and fills up a follow up Form 2 that gets sent back to the office. Form 1 and Form 2 are bound together in the same "service request" which is then cataloged and can be queried at a later date.

Please let me know what might work for this! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the PDF creation programs may work in the manner you are describing. One with which I am familiar is [Foxit Phantom PDF](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-editor/). You can create a document in another program such as Word, or create the document within the Foxit program, although the former method is easier, in my opinion.

Leave blank lines in the fields to be filled on the computer when saving the original creation. Opening/importing it into Foxit and running the form creator wizard will convert some (or all, if you're lucky) of the blanks into forms.

When the form fields are edited, fields with the same name will "auto-fill." That is to say, if the first page has the tenant's name and address in two fields, named "tenantname" and "tenant unit", when those same words are used on page two, the person entering the information will discover those fields have been completed.

The PDF you create would be two pages, rather than two documents. You would be able to save the PDF to be filled later, then print one page for one purpose, and another for the second, or print only the second and file all three away.

There may be a method in the advanced capabilities of this (or other PDF creation software) to share field date between independent files, but I've had experience only on the method described above.

The forms wizard can be used if you have created boxes for entering the data as well. The forms wizard can be bypassed once one has become familiar with the software.

Again, this applies only to my experience with the above noted program. I suspect that other competitive packages would have similar capabilities.